# If we allow DH operations in addition to exponentiation and multiplication can we get a lower bound for discrete logarithm?

Tags: nt.number-theory, cryptography

In https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/72969/proof-dlog-is-hard-in-generic-group-model/ it is shown if we allow only exponentiation and multiplication we can get an exponential complexity lower bound on discrete logarithm computation in the generic group model.

If in addition if we allow Diffie-Hellman operations as well, would there be any sort of exponential lower bound in the generic group model?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by Diffie-Hellman operations?

Comment: @CommandMaster: the Diffie-Hellman operation is: with inputs $G^a, G^b$, compute the value $G^{ab}$.  Quite common when talking about crypto; probably less so in general math...

Comment: The paper "Towards the Equivalence of Breaking the Diffie-Hellman Protocol and Computing Discrete Logarithms" by Maurer seems to suggest that for many cases it's fairly easy (although you do need a short advice string)

Comment: @CommandMaster I do not think the result is in Shoup's generic group model as you are talking about many 'cases' which means Maurer uses structure of the group and not a generic model.

Comment: It uses the size of the group and it being abelian, from what I could see, that's it